# Jenkins - where to approve the script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to run a pipeline script with some groovy. I am the admin of my jenkins. I get below error.

`org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper project`

[image]

But i am not getting any approve button. What is going on?

[image]

this is what i am trying to execute. nothing much

`def job = currentBuild.project.name`

Comment: could you please provide a code example to reproduce?

Comment: @biruk1230 `def job = currentBuild.project.name` - this is the only stuff i am trying to do the in the pipeline section

Comment: What version of Jenkins do you use?

Comment: my   version 2.155

Comment: Did you try to use `def job = currentBuild.projectName` ? For me it works fine.

Comment: @biruk1230, can u try this please `currentBuild.getExecutor().getOwner().hostName`

Comment: Your variant is not working, but `def hostName = currentBuild.build().getExecutor().getOwner().hostName` is working as well, however it returns something like "3519f9c2e8f7". If you want to get name of node, you can use `env.NODE_NAME`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure, but probably it can produce some bugs: you're using a weekly Jenkins release (2.155). I recommend you to use the last LST release (2.150.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow the link in the log of your failed build and then needed signature will load in the script approvals page.

Comment: which link? clicking on the above 'Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature' link loaded the next image

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Nothing seems to work for some reason. Not sure whats going on. I even tried with older versions 2.147.